# how to put the numeration of the first page of the chapter

Tags: chapters

```latex
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]
{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\bfseries\leftmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\bfseries\rightmark}}]
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

Comment: @MeriemDivitcha And where would you like the page number to go?

Comment: i want in in the top of the page on the right

Comment: Note that your settings do nothing at all, except printing on every header the chapter number and title. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, i want the number of the page of chapter appear in the top of the page

Comment: yes. the problem is that the numerate page all appear just the first page of the chapter

Comment: \fancyplain has been depreciated.  Instead use \fancypagestyle{plain}{...} (and update your packages).